# How to run batch script on logoff

Tags: windows-10, script

I'm trying to schedule a script to run at logoff on Microsoft Windows 10 Home (in particular, when I select "Shut Down" with fast startup enabled). I've created a test script

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff\temp_logoff.bat
```

with contents

```
echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\Logs\Test.txt
pause
```

I ran `gpedit.msc` and selected the script under

```
Local Computer Policy > User Configuration > Windows Settings > Script (Logon/Logoff)
```

[image: Selecting the script in the logoff settings dialog]

The script doesn't seem to be running at logoff (no lines were added to `C:\Logs\Test.txt`). I've read that `gpedit.msc` is supposed to write some registry entries. I found the following registry directory

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy
```

but there is no `Scripts` subdirectory. Do I need to do something else to get this script to run?

---

Additional information:

Running `gpresult /v`, I see

```
Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Local Group Policy
...

Resultant Set Of Policies for User
-----------------------------------
    ...
    Logoff Scripts
    --------------
        N/A
```

I also tried creating another policy for my specific user to no avail ([following this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-apply-local-group-policy-settings-specific-users-windows-10)).

Comment: Run gpresult or rsop.msc to check if the policy is applied. I would suggest to use Task scheduler to run such script instead - you can always see when and how the task has been run.

Comment: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy doesn't contain any settings from this part of GPO. It contains only those settings specified via Administrative templates.

Comment: Use the Task Scheduler. It's easier.

Comment: @Hardoman IIUC task scheduler doesn't have a logout trigger; the advice I've seen is to trigger on an undocumented system log with ID 7002, which seems fragile.

Comment: @Hardoman I ran gpresult as you suggested. It indicates the policy was applied but shows no logoff script.

Comment: @stewbasic that's absolutely normal to use event ID 7002 as a trigger. Regular practice.

Comment: @stewbasic if there is no logon script in the resultant policy that means: either policy is incorrectly configured, or there is another policy overriding it. Can you output policy to html file and attach it here? (gpresult /h c:\temp\res.html)

Comment: @Hardoman On my system gpresult doesn't seem to have a /h option. I'm starting to think that none of this works on windows home edition... I will try the task scheduler with event 7002 as you suggest. Still happy to get either a workaround or confirmation that this can't work, for future reference.